# Real time parsing

Tags: c++, json, parsing

I am quite new to parsing text files. While googling a bit, I found out that a parser builds a tree structure usually out of a text file. Most of the examples consists of parsing files, which in my view is quite static. You load the file to parser and get the output.

My problem is something different from parsing files. I have a stream of JSON data coming from a server socket at TCP port 6000. I need to parse the incoming data.I have some questions in mind:

1) Do I need to save the incoming JSON data at the client side with some sought of buffer? Answer: I think yes I need to save it, but are there any parsers which can do it directly like passing the JSON object as an argument to the parse function.

2) How would the structure of the real time parser look like`? Answer: Since on google only static parsing tree structure is available. In my view each object is parsed and have some sought of parsed tree and then it is deleted from the memory. Otherwise it will cause memory overflow because the data is continuous.

There are some parser libraries available like JSON-C and JSON lib. One more thing which comes into my mind is that can we save a JSON object in any C/C++ array. Just thought of that but could realize how to do that.

Comment: Your real question is unclear!

Comment: There are many libraries to parse JSON (as you notice). Use them! Don't do it yourself.

Comment: If you still want to do the parsing itself (which will be very hard if you're a beginner) then simply read all of the data into a buffer, and parse the buffer once all data has been received.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg is there any libraries available which support JSON object in C/C++ or I can use a char buffer with some conditions to specify one complete message? I found this library useful :https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: Asking for links to libraries is off-topic for stackoverflow.com, so you have to search yourself. But before you do that you need to think about what you really need, what the use-cases are, if you want to do [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) of actual C++ objects, or just send/receive formatted and nested data. And yes, there are C++-specific libraries.